# How to avoid maven compiling testClass in normale compiling

Tags: testing, maven, dependency-management

I have a default maven project:

- /src/main/java
- /src/test/java (include *Test.java).

When I exeucte "mvn compile", maven also tries to compile the testClasses under /src/test/java. This fails, as of some dependencies such as JUnit are under "test"-scope. Changing the scope of e.g. JUnit to "provided" everything works fine.

How can I avoid maven to compile testClasses when compiling? In my understanding, I expect to maven to compile this files only when executing "testcompile".

I am using maven 2.2.1

Comment: Can you post the relevant bits of your `pom`? In theory, if you just do `mvn compile` it should not attempt to compile your test classes. What command are you running?

Comment: you have to have made some tweaks to your `pom` for to see the behaviour you are claiming. Please consider posting you `pom.xml` (and any referenced `<parent>` poms too) or better yet the output from `mvn help:effective-pom`. Most likely you have tweaked the source file locations and now Maven thinks that your test classes are also production classes

Comment: The dependency scope for JUnit "provided" is simply wrong. You should use "test" scope instead. If tests are not compiled correctly they should be fixed.

Comment: The hint by Stephen Conolly saved my issue, I had defined "sourceDirectory" wronly. Thank you!

Comment: if u have even modified the source directory, how come you claim your project being "default maven project"? I wish you can give accurrate questions next time, because it is a waste of not only yours but other people's effort and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pom.xml had defined "sourceDirectory" incorrectly. Removing it fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is nothing to do with the scope of JUnit.  Normally we set JUnit's scope to `test` (instead of `provided`) and everything is just fine.

`src/test/java` is compiled by Maven Compiler Plugin's testCompile goal.  However, you don't need to explicitly run that goal.  Please have a look in topics about Maven's Lifecycle.  For example, if you run maven install, it is implicitly going through many phases (e.g. compile, compile test, generate resources etc), and many of them is bounded to a default plugin goal.

If you want to avoid test source from building, from Maven [Compiler Plugin's usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html#skip), `compiler:testCompile` will be skipped if you turn off testing by setting `maven.test.skip=true`

So, if your unit tests are not yet ready, just build with Maven, with `-Dmaven.test.skip=true` parameter.

Just to add, this is absolutely not a good practice to assume "unit test failing" being normal during development.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
My attempt is not to skip tests while building, changing JUnit's scope to "provided" is my workaround. Anyhow, the testClasses are compiled in maven-"compile" already, not in "test-compile" (which is after "compile") - I wonder for the reason and like'd to know how to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [skip](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skip) parameter for the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) which skip tests as well as compiling the test.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of command "maven clean compile" , use "mvn  -B -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean compile". This parameter skips test.